# Group records by selected values into different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have following example:

```
create table products (name text, id integer, type smallint, category integer);

insert into products values 
('apple', 23, 1, 1200),
('apple', 23, 1, 999),
('apple', 31, 2, 1200),
('apple', 23, 3, 1200),
('orange', 10, 1, 200),
('orange', 10, 2, 200),
('orange', 10, 2, 230),
('orange', 10, 3, 200),
('orange', 64, 1, 700),
('orange', 70, 2, 700);
```

[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/i_sGOZpu)

I want the results to be like this:

| name | type_1_3_id | type_2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 23 | 31 |
| orange | {10,64} | {10,70} |

But postgres forces me to group by column type, which makes my results not as I want them to be

```
select distinct name, 
case when type in (1,3) then array_agg(distinct id) end as type_1_3,
case when type = 2 then array_agg(distinct id) end as type_2
from products
group by 1, type
order by 1
```

Comment: No distinct before name, and group by name and type ?

Comment: Try the opposite, put the case expression as arguments to array_agg.

Comment: @jarlh yeah, that one works :)
array_remove(array_agg(distinct case when type in (1,3) then id end), null) as type_1_3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `filter` clause with your `array_agg` function:

```
select name, 
 array_agg(distinct id) filter (where type in (1,3)) as type_1_3,
 array_agg(distinct id) filter (where type = 2) as type_2
from products
group by 1
order by 1
```

With conditional aggregation `array_agg(case when... then ... end)` a null value is returned for the unmatched rows, while filters would aggregate only the specified rows within the where clause.

> If [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html) is specified, then only the input rows for which the filter_clause evaluates to true are fed to the aggregate function; other rows are discarded.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SnShDnu7)

Comment: Great answer. I always forget the `FILTER` clause available in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want `DISTINCT` values and also you want to exclude nulls, you can't use `ARRAY_AGG()` out of the box. You can filter and aggregate separately and then join these aggregations.

For example:

```
select coalesce(x.name, y.name) as name, x.a as type_1_3, y.a as type_2
from (
  select name, array_agg(distinct id) as a 
  from products where type in (1, 3) group by name
) x
full join (
  select name, array_agg(distinct id) as a 
  from products where type = 2 group by name
) y on y.name = x.name
```

Result:

```
 name    type_1_3  type_2  
 ------- --------- ------- 
 apple   {23}      {31}    
 orange  {10,64}   {10,70}
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/toCQwo8x).